# Multiple sourcesets configurations

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I have two `productFlavors`

```
productFlavors {
    dev {
        ...
    }

    ble {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, I created a different source set for `ble` where I added few extra Java classes.

So I have two sets of directories now:

1. `app/src/main/java/...`
2. `app/src/ble/java/...`

In the `ble` set, I have a Java class called `BLEUtil.java`

```
app/src/ble/java/.../BLEUtil.java
```

I want to call a method that is in `BLEUtil.java` from my `MainActivity`

```java
BLEUtil.startScan();
```

When the build variant is set to `bleDebug`, it works great because `BLEUtil.java` exist.

However, when I change my build variant to `devDebug`, `BLEUtil.java` does not exist so `BLEUtil.startScan()` throws an error and I can't build the app.

```java
error: cannot find symbol class BLEUtil
```

Do I have to comment and uncomment those lines out manually or is there any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `MainActivity` is in `main`, you can:

- Have a `BLEUtil` class in `dev` as well, with the same API, perhaps implemented as a no-op; or
- Have two `MainActivity` implementations, one in `dev` and one in `ble`,  where only the one in `ble` uses `BLEUtil`, and perhaps with some common base class in `main` that has the common functionality; or
- Have `MainActivity` inherit from a `FlavoredActivity`, where you have implementations of `FlavoredActivity` in both `dev` and `ble`, where the latter uses `BLEUtil`

There may be other approaches as well.

Comment: Thank! So the first option is what I was hoping to do. However, I can't have `BLEUtil` in `main` right? The fact is I have over 6 `productFlavors` so I would have to have `BLEUtil` in each one?

Comment: @ᴛʜᴇᴘᴀᴛᴇʟ: "However, I can't have BLEUtil in main right? " -- correct. "The fact is I have over 6 productFlavors so I would have to have BLEUtil in each one?" -- also correct.

Comment: appreciate it! Thanks